# python Dictionary Column sum

Tags: python, dictionary

I have table in format of dictionary. I am trying to add total row in a last. we can traverse through each item and find sum. Is there any optimized solution?

**Example:**

```
items = {"red":[2,5,7], "yellow":[4,6,7]}
```

**Output:**

```
{"red":[2,5,7], "yellow":[4,6,7], "Total":[6,11,14]}
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: note that the word "last" is undefined here. Dictionaries have no order, so no element is first or last.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will add the desired item to `items`:

```
items['Total'] = map( sum, zip(*items.values()) )
```

- `items.values()` gets you the lists of numbers.  For the example data, this would be `[[2,5,7],[4,6,7]]`
- `zip(*items.values())` *pivots* that list of lists, giving you a list grouping values at the same index together.  For the example, this would be `[[2,4],[5,6],[7,7]]`
- We `map` the `sum` function over these lists, giving you the sum sequence of sums desired.
- Finally, this gets assigned to the desired element of `items`.

Answer (score 0):

you can sum the values like this:

```
items = {"red":[2,5,7], "yellow":[4,6,7]}

items["total"] = [sum(i) for i in zip(*items.values())]
```

as result you will have:

```
>items
=> {'red': [2, 5, 7], 'yellow': [4, 6, 7], 'total': [6, 11, 14]}
```

`

Comment: The comments were identical, I thought there was no problem.... I edited